# Alternate email sending service - eg: AWS SES

Tags: plugins, email, amazon, web-services

I noticed my shared hosting service have a delayed email sending service. 
This is not good to serve my WordPress site.

Is there a solution for this (eg. plugin) that can plug into another email service such as AWS SES? If so how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this plugin on websites to connect to AWS SES or SendGrid: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

You can see more SMTP plugins here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/smtp/